# Remove [ and ] from a dataframe column - R

Tags: r

Using this code I try to remove the characters [ and ] from column data.

Code:

```
colA <- 1:4
colB <- ("[123 123;22 34;556 55; 23 22]")
tryDF <- data.frame(colA, colB)
gsub("[","",tryDF$ColB)
gsub("]","",tryDF$ColB)
```

but I get this error:

```
Error in gsub("[", "", tryDF$ColB) : 
  invalid regular expression '[', reason 'Missing ']''
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub("[", "", tryDF$ColB) : TRE pattern compilation error 'Missing ']''
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: `gsub("\\[|\\]","",tryDF$colB)`?

Comment: You must escape the `[`. Use `"\\["`.

Comment: or `gsub("[][]", "", "[123 123;22 34;556 55; 23 22]")`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the `[` and `]` values by:

```
gsub("[][]", "", tryDF$colB)
```

Since `[` and `]` mean to enclose something in regrex, you are enclosing `][`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways:

a) with alternation:

```
 gsub("\\[|\\]", "", tryDF$colB)
```

b) with anchors (since, in your case, `[` and `]` always occur in string-first and, respectively, string-last position):

```
gsub("^.|.$", "", tryDF$colB)
```

c) with negative lookahead to exclude whitespace and `;`from the `\\W` character class (with capital `W`; it matches any non-alphanumeric character, hence also `[]`):

```
gsub("(?![\\s;])\\W", "", tryDF$colB, perl = TRUE)
```